# Can you use a different distribution certificate on the same iOS enterprise account to sign an app?

Tags: ios, certificate, enterprise, ad-hoc-distribution

Can you use a different distribution certificate on the same iOS enterprise account to sign an app that was originally signed by a different certificate on the same account?

We no longer have access to the private key on the original certificate. Is it as simple as just creating a new distribution certificate and signing the new build?

Comment: Yes, it should be that easy.

Comment: I've done this previously using a regular account where the certificate was expiring and I created a new one to sign the build while leaving the other as is. I just want to double check that my thinking is right. Thanks!